# How do we perform line/statement coverage using bullseye coverage tool?

Tags: c, bullseye

Is there some tutorial available for Bullseye code coverage tool. Is it automated? How do we find line coverage using this tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function coverage and decision coverage are supported in Bullseye coverage tool.I dont think line coverage/statement coverage is supported. Please see this link.

http://www.bullseye.com/measurementTechnique.html

Comment: I am not really sure if they have a proper documentation as such. But to know more about the coverage details, its available in their website